# Wordpress Website not loading proper Image URL's for background

Tags: php, jquery, css, divi

Website link: https://colindedeugd.nl/stories

I have build a website with Wordpress and Divi. I am running into an issue, I hope you know the problem!

I have a custom Divi Blog Module. This not only grabs the default information from my blog posts, but also the info from a custom ACF image field (this was done with the help of Divi support, and some changes to my child theme and seems to work). The code below should then load the image from this custom field (currently set as Image URL return format) and input it as the module background. It get's as far as loading the correct image ID (I checked this with the inspect element tool) but fails to properly load the image. I hope someone knows what is going wrong! Here's the Javascript code I added to the page:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Searches for the Divi Blog Modules with this CSS Class where I want the background replaced
    var $module = $('.acf-blog-bg');
    
    // Checks if the module exists on the page
    if ($module.length) {
        // Retrieve the URL of the featured image using PHP
        var imageUrl = "<?php echo esc_js(wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'featured_portrait', true))); ?>";
        
        // Check if the image URL is not empty
        if (imageUrl !== '') {
            // Sets the background of the module to the URL of the image file
            $module.css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm not a coder and this code was written with ChatGPT, so if there are any glaring issues please let me know! I hope someone finds the fix! Thanks!

---

For some additional context:

This was added to Blog.php (a copy of the Blog.php Module in my child theme) at around line 1640, to grab the data from the custom image field

```
                    $featured_portrait = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured_portrait', true) ? get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured_portrait', true) : "";
if($featured_portrait != "") { 
    echo '<div class="featured_portrait"><img src="' . $featured_portrait . '" alt="Featured Portrait"></div>'; 
}
```

And this was added to my functions.php to load the custom Blog Module:

```
function divi_custom_blog_module() { 
get_template_part( '/includes/Blog' ); 
$dcfm = new custom_ET_Builder_Module_Blog(); 
remove_shortcode( 'et_pb_blog' ); 
add_shortcode( 'et_pb_blog', array( $dcfm, '_shortcode_callback' ) ); } 

add_action( 'et_builder_ready', 'divi_custom_blog_module' ); 

function divi_custom_blog_class( $classlist ) { 
// Blog Module 'classname' overwrite. 
$classlist['et_pb_blog'] = array( 'classname' => 'custom_ET_Builder_Module_Blog',); 
return $classlist; 
} 

add_filter( 'et_module_classes', 'divi_custom_blog_class' );
```

Comment: Inspect the value of `imageUrl`, does it look like a URL? If you copy and paste that URL into your browser, does it return an image?

Comment: Hey @ChrisHaas, sorry but... how do I do that? If it helps, I added the website page link on top, I forgot earlier. And some extra info to see how the code links up to each other.

Comment: Right click and view the page's source (_not_ inspect). Search for `imageUrl`. You'll see the actual PHP code itself, which means the code you pasted in is being sent literally, and not interpreted as PHP.

Comment: Ahh I see! What it returns is the following URL: `http://812`

This is not a proper URL, it is however the right image ID. So something is going wrong in grabbing the URL from the image with that ID.

When I'm logged in at the media page it's: https://colindedeugd.nl/wp-admin/upload.php?item=812 (there you can see the ID)
And this is the proper URL which needs to be fetched: https://colindedeugd.nl/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/Thumbs-Tall-NS-Oliebollenboys.jpg).

Comment: The `http://812` appears to be a different problem, at least as far as what you originally posted. I think we should focus on the JavaScript block you posted first. I don't know where in the backend you placed it, but the PHP code isn't being executed. Technically speaking, you don't actually have JavaScript. Instead, you have PHP code that happens to be emitting JavaScript. For security reasons, whatever you place in that JavaScript area (or even in a WYSIWYG) will not be executed as PHP.

Comment: I don't use Divi, or know much about it. When I want to do something with PHP I actually edit PHP files on the server. So if you have such access, you might need to put that code there instead.

Comment: Thanks! At first I had placed the code in my website < head > but this also did not work.

I do have access to the php files, so I put the code in a .js file in js directory and added the following code to my functions.php file to enqueue:

`wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/background-customacf-loadscript.js' ); 

} 



add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mycustomscript_enqueue' );`

Unfortunately it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

So your main problem is that you are enqueue a JavaScript file and your browser is requesting it. Because the file ends with `.js`, the PHP interpreter doesn't kick in.

You *could* try renaming it to `.php`, and that'd honestly work, however it wouldn't be run in a "WordPress context", so functions such as `get_the_ID` would fail. Some people attempt to fix this by booting a mini copy of WordPress then, however in this case it would still fail because the URL of the JavaScript file doesn't tell WordPress anything about the page holding it, so WordPress wouldn't know the page and thus the field on it.

The better solution is probably to create a JavaScript variable that holds the result of the PHP execution, which is exactly what `wp_localize_script` does.

In the code below I'm enqueuing your JavaScript in mostly the same way as you were doing it before. After enqueueing, I'm then calling `wp_localize_script` with the result of your `wp_get_attachment_url` call.

```php
add_action(
    'wp_enqueue_scripts',
    static function () {

        // The following three conditions are effectively the same as you had before in
        // a one-liner, I've just broken them out for clarity. If this ever stops working,
        // instead of "return" you can "echo 'first block';" or "echo 'second block';".
        if (!$id = get_the_ID()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$featuredPortrait = get_post_meta($id, 'featured_portrait', true)) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$imageUrl = wp_get_attachment_url($featuredPortrait)) {
            return;
        }

        // Let's give it a more descriptive name. We'll use this both for
        // enqueuing the script and for localizing the script.
        $customScriptName = 'colindedeugd-custom-scripts';

        wp_enqueue_script(
            $customScriptName,
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/background-customacf-loadscript.js'
        );
        
        // Although "localize" is associated with internationalization, it's also
        // used to pass data from PHP to JavaScript. This will create a global
        // JavaScript variable called "colindedeugd_custom_scripts" with a property
        // called "imageUrl" that contains the URL of the featured image.
        wp_localize_script(
            $customScriptName,
            'colindedeugd_custom_scripts',
            [
                'imageUrl' => $imageUrl,
            ]
        );
    }
);
```

The result of the above is that a global variable called `window.colindedeugd_custom_scripts.imageUrl` will be created, and that should hold your URL for you.

Assuming the first block of JavaScript is what was in `background-customacf-loadscript.js` (minus the script tags), you can replace it with:

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        // Searches for the Divi Blog Modules with this CSS Class where I want the background replaced
        var $module = $('.acf-blog-bg');

        // Checks if the module exists on the page
        if ($module.length) {
            // Retrieve the URL of the featured image using PHP
            var imageUrl = window.colindedeugd_custom_scripts.imageUrl;

            // Check if the image URL is not empty
            if (imageUrl !== '') {
                // Sets the background of the module to the URL of the image file
                $module.css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: First off I wanna say thanks so much for taking the time to do this! I really appreciate it. As you can see on the webpage: `https://colindedeugd.nl/stories/` the images finally appeared again, so it definitely did something good!
Unfortunately I came back to the same problem which I had before I came here (and what I tried to fix with the custom Divi code) which is that each of the post has a different image set in the Featured Portrait field, and for some reason they all just grab the image from the most recent post, ignoring the offset I set in the Blog Module.

Comment: It seems like such a niche issue and a lot of work, if it's not possible I will just do it by hand, which seems like the easy way out now, haha.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you are looking for some kind of loop. Unfortunately that's probably beyond anything I'll be able to help you with in answers and comments here. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone comes across this, I found a different way that finally fixes the problem. Turns out I was going down a difficult route. Here's how you do it:

First, we need to make sure the blog meta gets shown on top of the featured image, instead of below. (credits to: https://www.peeayecreative.com/how-to-move-the-divi-blog-title-text-and-button-over-the-image/)

Give the Blog Modules you want to apply this to the following CSS Class `pa-blog` and paste this in your functions.php or in a Code Module:

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".pa-blog .et_pb_post").each(function() {
                $(this).find(".entry-title, .post-meta, .post-content ").wrapAll('<div class="pa-blog-text"></div>');
            });
            //Do the same for ajax
            $(document).bind('ready ajaxComplete', function() {
                $(".pa-blog .et_pb_post").each(function() {
                    $(this).find(".entry-title, .post-meta, .post-content ").wrapAll('<div class="pa-blog-text"></div>');
                });
            });
        });
    })(jQuery); 
</script>
```

Next, we need to add this to our Theme Options > Custom CSS:

```
/*move wrapped title, meta, and text up over the image*/
.pa-blog-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}
/*keep the moved items positioned with their parent items*/
.et_pb_blog_grid article {
    position: relative;
}
/*remove spacing around entire blog post*/
.et_pb_blog_grid .et_pb_post {
    padding: 0px;
}
/*remove negative margins on blog featured image*/
.et_pb_image_container {
    margin: 0;
}
/*remove the margin below the featured image frame*/
.et_pb_post .entry-featured-image-url {
    margin: 0;
}
.et_pb_blog_grid .entry-featured-image-url::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

We can use this to style our module. For example, to change the margins around the text field, you can change the padding.
There is one thing left. By default, Divi shows the Featured Images as a 1x1 image. You can set this to be a custom size (https://www.peeayecreative.com/change-the-divi-blog-image-aspect-ratio/) or what I'm doing, stop Divi from cropping them altogether (https://www.peeayecreative.com/change-the-divi-blog-image-aspect-ratio/). You can then set your own size by uploading your images in the correct dimensions.

To stop Divi from cropping, paste this in your functions.php:

```
function wpc_remove_height_cropping($height) {
    return '9999';
}
function wpc_remove_width_cropping($width) {
    return '9999';
}

add_filter( 'et_pb_blog_image_height', 'wpc_remove_height_cropping' );
add_filter( 'et_pb_blog_image_width', 'wpc_remove_width_cropping' );
```

Unfortunately what I needed at first, to change the source where the Featured Image comes from, is not possible, because Dynamic Content is based on the content of the current page, not from the posts. But at least with this method the image will automatically change!